# How to merge table from access to SQL Express?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ms-access

I have one table named "Staff" in access and also have this table(same name) in SQL 2008. 
Both table have thousands of records. I want to merge records from the access table to sql table without affecting the existing records in sql. Normally, I just export using OCBC driver and that works fine if that table doesn't exist in sql server. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Are there records in the Access table that are also in the SQL Server table, or are the two sets of records disjunct?

Comment: Eg. I got a table named 'Visit'. 600 records in Access table and 300 records in SQL table. After inserting the data from access to sql, I want 900 records in SQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple append query from the local access table to the linked sql server table should work just fine in this case.

So, just drop in the first (from) table into the query builder. Then change the query type to append, and you are prompted for the append table name.

From that point on, just drop in the columns you want (do not drop in the PK column, as they need not be used nor transferred in this case).

You can also type in the sql directly in the query builder. Either way, you will wind up with something like:

```
INSERT INTO dbo_custsql 
  ( ADMINID, Amount, Notes, Status )
  SELECT ADMINID, Amount, Notes, Status
FROM custsql1;
```

Comment: What if there are duplicate records?

Answer (score 0):

This may help: http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/

Or you could write a simple program to read from each data set and do the comparison, adding, updating, and deleting, etc.

Comment: SQL Compare synchronizes the schema. For data, you'll need to use http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/